How does Python know that the comma in the lambda function does not indicate another parameter of map fun
list(map(lambda x,y : x*y , listA, listB))

I want to know how Python understands that the comma present in lambda x,y belongs to the lambda function and it is not the end of the first parameter of the map function.

Python knows that the lambda function definition isn't complete yet because of the colon :. The syntax of lambda functions is:
lambda args: expression

where there could be any number of arguments and all arguments are also optional. Thus, this expression
lambda: print('in lambda')

works, so does this:
lambda arg1, arg2, arg3: sum([arg1, arg2, arg3])

When evaluating this expression:
list(map(lambda x,y : x*y , listA, listB))

Python knows that the comma between x and y belong to the lambda function because the colon expected had not yet been reached. Once Python reaches the colon, it will expect an expression, in this case, x*y, which completes the lambda function definition. Any comma found will now be evaluated as an argument separator to the map function
